# How can I get some info from Wi-Fi server in android before the device completes booting up

Tags: java, android, eclipse, boot

I am trying, with programming in Java-Eclipse to **get** a simple string from   my Wi-Fi Server through an http request.  The problem is that I want to have that string Info available in an Android Service **before** the Android Device prompts the user for  an entry code, that is before it completes booting up.  Is there any way to achieve that with java -Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

As a normal app? No.

AFAIK, the earliest event a normal app can get is [BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) which, as its name suggests, happens when the boot is completed.